# jQuery Masonry item order

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

How can I get masonry to respect more of the original item order here? I would like the order to be dolphins, fish, invertebrates, pinnipeds:

```
var $container = jQuery('.tax-product_cat #content');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: 'li.product',
        gutterWidth: 22
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you checkout the demo I provided? If you're able to get it to work, can you accept my answer please? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The masonry plugin doesn't provide much in the way or sorting options, as you can see in their [API](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html). The Isotope plugin by the same author however, does offer a plethora of sorting options.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Just so you know, you can wrap all your jQuery code like this `(function($){ //your code here })(jQuery);`

```
var container = $('.tax-product_cat #content');

container.isotope({
  itemSelector : 'ul li',
  getSortData : {
    category : function (el) {
      // el refers to each item matching `itemSelector`
      return el.find('h3').text().trim();
    }
  },
  sortBy : 'category',
  sortAscending : true
});
```

Here's the sorting reference. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html
Also the documentation specifies a few additional sortBy params:

- 'original-order' will use the original order of the item elements to arrange them in the layout.
- 'random' is a random order.

Here's a simple demo, showing everything to make it work. Try and grok what the code is doing and adjust your code to do the same. If it's not sorting them like you want, try and figure out what mode you need. See the getSortData object? `category` is something that *you* define. It's completely arbitrary. You can make a `backwards` category and just write the function to return the data the proper way.

http://jsfiddle.net/SRW6g/19/embedded/result/

Comment: you can change the ```sortAscending``` flag as necessary.

Comment: var $container = jQuery('.tax-product_cat #content');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'li.product',
     getSortData : {
        category : function (el) {
          // el refers to each item matching `itemSelector`
          return el.find('h3').text().trim();
        }
      },
      sortBy : 'category',
      sortAscending : true,
 masonry: {
        columnWidth: 245,
     gutterWidth: 22
      }
      });

Comment: In the above, the sort does not seem to have any effect. I get the same results as with masonry.

Comment: Are you checking your dev console? I see a host of errors. 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addTest' jquery.isotope.min.js:11

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined cornforth.js:23

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope' cornforth.js:5

Answer (score 3):

Latest masonry support the order with `horizontalOrder: true` settings.

Comment: are you certain about that? i'm using version 9.2.0 and am experiencing the same issue as the poster. the order of the elements withing the masonary depend on the order which the images are loaded in.

Answer (score 2):

There is [plugin - "masonry-ordered"](http://masonry-ordered.tasuki.org/) for jquery masonry to make sort behave like

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Pity, that this plugin only works with version 2.0. For my needs I could downgrade to Masonry v2.x. Thanks!